# Strange behaviour with textarea autogrow and CSS box-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an textarea autogrow with Javascript. The logic is fairly simple, and here is my working code :

```js
$("#message-box").on('keydown', function() {
  var scroll_height = $("#message-box").get(0).scrollHeight;
  $("#message-box").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');
});
```

```css
#message-box {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message-box"></textarea>
```

Everything works great, but when I remove the `box-sizing: border-box;` property, I see strange things. **With each keydown event the textarea autogrows**.

What is the relation between textarea autogrowing and the `box-sizing` property ?

***EDIT***

See the demos here :

With the box-sizing property : http://52.90.45.189/aks/textarea-autogrow.html

Without the box-sizing property : http://52.90.45.189/aks/textarea-autogrow-no-border-box.html

I can understand that scrollHeight increases by 10px when box-sizing is removed. But why does the browser add an extra 10px **each time** when a key is pressed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `scrollHeight` taking `padding: 5px;` as a content which is increasing scroll height of `textarea`

> The Element.scrollHeight read-only property is a measurement of the
>   height of an element's content, including content not visible on the
>   screen due to overflow.
>
> The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum height the element
>   would require in order to fit all the content in the viewpoint without
>   using a vertical scrollbar. It includes the element's padding, but not
>   its border or margin.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

---

With *border-box* textarea's height is `100px` excluding `padding` so scrollheight is `100px`.

With *content-box* textarea's height is `100px + 10px` as per default behavior of `content-box` so scrollheight is `110px`, with each keydown textarea increases it's height by 10px and updated scrollheight as well.

See snippet Below

```js
$("#message-box").on('keydown', function() {
  console.log("height of teaxtare on keydown is " + $("#message-box").height() + "px");
  var scroll_height = $("#message-box").get(0).scrollHeight;

  console.log("Scroll Height of textarea is " + scroll_height + "px");
  $("#message-box").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');
  console.log("After setting scroll_height as a height of teaxtare, teaxtare's height is " + $("#message-box").height() + "px");
});
```

```css
#message-box {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<textarea id="message-box"></textarea>
```

**EDIT**

Let say

`S` = `110px` (`scrollheight + padding:5px;`)

`H` = Height of textarea.

Now you presses key,

```
Key Event 1,
S = 110px so
H = 110px,
____

Key Event 2,
S = 120 // 110px (which is increased height of textarea by this function ($("#message-box").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');)) + Padding (Which is 10px) 
H = 120px,
 ____

Key Event 3,
S = 130 // 120px (which is increased height of textarea by this function ($("#message-box").css('height', scroll_height + 'px');)) + Padding (Which is 10px) 
H = 130px,

And So On
```

This formation is sort of loop.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But why does padding is added with EACH keydown event ? Should it not be included only ONCE ?

Comment: It is included once, but it is adding into height of element every time 
 that's why scrollheight is greater than actual height.

Comment: But why should it be added each time ?

Comment: Because each time you press key there is some padding which is including into height (as per default behavior of `content-box`) and increasing elements scroll height. Set `padding:0` you will notice the difference.

Comment: Why should padding be added to height each time ? According to CSS box model padding area and content area is different. When I type in the textbox, I am just adding to content area.

Comment: I understand scrollHeight will include the content area and the padding (top & bottom). But when I type in 5 keys, why should the height be increased by 50px (5 * 10) ?

Comment: @UsefulAngle Updated my answer, I hope this will help you to understand

Comment: I got it. Updating the height updates the scrollHeight as well, and to that padding is added. Its almost like a loop. Man ! Really thanks a lot for your effort !

Answer (score 2):

In your JQuery, you can Use:

```
this.style.height = "1px";
this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
```

Please try the following:

```js
$("#message-box").on('keydown', function() {
    this.style.height = "1px";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px"; 
});
```

```css
#message-box {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="message-box"></textarea>
```

Comment: My code works, but when I remove border-box property, things go strange. Try removing the border-box property from my code.

Answer (score 0):

In first loop iteration the CSS height was `100px` but `scrollHeight` was `110px`. These two are different things. Again in the 2nd loop iteration, `scrollHeight` was `120px` and the CSS height before the last line of the function was `110px`. After the last line the CSS height changed to `120px`.

```
this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
```

`scrollHeight` is real height of the element. CSS height is the real height with `border-box` and not with `content-box`.